# How do I reference the secondary ranges in Terraform code?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to reference secondary ranges in another resource:

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "mysubnetwork" {
  name          = "mysubnetwork"
  ....
  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = "mysecondary"
    ip_cidr_range = "10.0.0.0/24"
  }
  ....

resource "google_container_cluster" "my-cluster" {
....
ip_allocation_policy{
    cluster_secondary_range_name = <reference my existing secondary ranges>
    services_secondary_range_name = <reference my existing secondary ranges>
}
```

Tried this: `google_compute_subnetwork.mysubnetwork.secondary_ip_range.range_name["mysecondary"]`

but got `This value does not have any attributes.`

I tried this: `google_compute_subnetwork.mysubnetwork.secondary_ip_range.range_name.mysecondary`

but got the same error.

Comment: Do you only ever have a single secondary IP range? If so it could be as simple as `google_compute_subnetwork.mysubnetwork.secondary_ip_range.0.range_name` for the `range_name` and `google_compute_subnetwork.mysubnetwork.secondary_ip_range.0.ip_cidr_range` for the `cidr_range`. If you have variable amounts of ranges then the question is a bit trickier.

Comment: i have 2 secondary ranges and i dont want to reference them by index. I want to reference them by their name

Comment: But are they static or are they dynamic? If you always want to refer to the first one with one resource and the second one with another resource then it's just a case of using `google_compute_subnetwork.mysubnetwork.secondary_ip_range.0.range_name` and `google_compute_subnetwork.mysubnetwork.secondary_ip_range.1.range_name`.

Comment: I dont want to do that. for readability sake I want to see the range name being referenced in the config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is convoluted and I havent tested yet but seem like it will work- will I run into issues with this? Want to know if there is a preferable way. For clarity it should be obvious what range is being referenced (so not using an index number)

```
variable "vpc_secondary_ip_ranges" {
  type = map(object({
    secondary_range = object({
      range_name = string
      ip_cidr_range = string
    })
  }))
  default = {
    gke-pods = {
      secondary_range = {
        range_name = "gke-pods"
        ip_cidr_range = "10.1.0.0/14"
      }
    }
    gke-services = {
      secondary_range = {
        range_name = "gke-services"
        ip_cidr_range = "10.2.2.0/24"
      }
    }
  }
}

// flatten for secondary_ip_range parameter
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "bombora-default-subnetwork-us-west1" {
  secondary_ip_range = [for r in var.vpc_secondary_ip_ranges : r.secondary_range]
  ...

...
resource "google_container_cluster" "mycluster" {
  // index into map for names of secondaries for ip_allocation_policy
  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name = var.vpc_secondary_ip_ranges.gke-pods.secondary_range.range_name
    services_secondary_range_name = var.vpc_secondary_ip_ranges.gke-services.secondary_range.range_name
  }
....
```